# Why is the Winklevoss ETF decision so important, when this tracker certificate already exists?

Tags: trading, banks

The Winklevoss ETF and the SEC decisions regarding it seem to be on everyone's lips and the influence of the bitcoin price are apparent.

However there seems to be this tracker certificate already: 
https://zertifikate.vontobel.com/DE/Produkt/DE000VN5MJG9
(Site is in German, sorry. Basically a tracker certifate on BTC/EUR with a factor of 1/10. ISIN: DE000VN5MJG9)

Why do I not see it anywhere in the news and why is the Winklevoss ETF so important then?

Answer (score 1):

This ETF is for US people and would be traded on [BATS exchange](http://www.bats.com). US is a big financial market. Plus it's a hot topic because famous Winklevoss brothers are behind it.

Comment: Would it be much of a hassle for a US based investor to buy the certificate I mentioned? Based in Germany I can trade internationally on basically any exchange I want to with my online broker. Is this different for you in the US?